# wxNotebook and wxBoxSizer behaviour

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a GUI with two wxNotebook-elements like this:

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "My App",size=(800,600),pos=((wx.DisplaySize()[0]-800)/2,(wx.DisplaySize()[1]-600)/2),style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)

        self.SetBackgroundColour((232,232,232))
        self.p = wx.Panel(self,size=(800,6300),pos=(0,0))
        self.SetPages()

    def SetPages(self):
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self.p,style=wx.NB_BOTTOM)
        page1 = PageOne(self.nb)
        page2 = PageTwo(self.nb)
        self.nb.AddPage(page1, "page1")
        self.nb.AddPage(page2, "page2")
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.p.SetSizer(self.sizer)
```

Now I want to create a third Notebook-page & set focus on it at a certain event. But this does not work:

```
def CreateNewPageEvent(self, event):
    self.CreateNewPage()

def CreateNewPage(self):
    page3 = PageThree(self.nb)
    self.nb.AddPage(page3, "page3")
```

I must admit that I'm not sure what a "BoxSizer" does =/
Any ideas to get this working?

Edit: OK, this works for an event inside my MainFrame-class. But I also want to create a new nb-page from an event of another class:

```
class ContinueApp(MainFrame):
    def foo(self):
        super(ContinueApp, self).CreateNewPage()

def continueapp(event):
    cont = ContinueApp()
    cont.foo()
```

Comment: It's a bit like a `TableLayout` in xml, if that helps. Or like a table into which you put different widgets. With either columns (vertical sizer) or rows (horizontal). You can combine them or use a `GridBagSizer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BoxSizer (and other sizers) are for laying out widgets so you don't have to position them yourself. They also help control which widgets expand or stretch when you make your application window larger or smaller. In your case, you should NOT add the same widget to the same sizer twice. You shouldn't add one widget to two different sizers either.

You need to remove this:

```
self.nb.AddPage(page1, "page3")
self.sizer.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
self.p.SetSizer(self.sizer)
```

Also note that you are adding page1 to the notebook again when you should be adding page3:

```
page3 = PageThree(self.nb)
self.nb.AddPage(page3, "page3")
```

If you want to switch between tabs programmatically, you should use the notebook's SetSelection method. I have an example app you can look at in the following tutorial (or the answer below it):

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/18/wxpython-how-to-programmatically-change-wx-notebook-pages/
- [wxpython: How to make a tab active once it is opened via an event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387835/wxpython-how-to-make-a-tab-active-once-it-is-opened-via-an-event-handler)

Once you have switched tabs, you may want to set the focus on a widget within that tab. I find that using pubsub to send events is probably the cleanest way to communicate between classes. I have a couple of tutorials on that subject:

- For early versions of wxPython 2.8 - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/
- For later versions of wxPython 2.8 and all of 2.9 - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you! This solved one part of my problem. But there is another problem as I just edited in my start-post. P.S. with "print-debugging" I can see that "CreateNewPage" is called from my other class - but no nb-page appears.

Comment: Well that's where pubsub comes in. Create a listener in your MainFrame class that will call your CreateNewPage method. Then in your ContinueApp you can publish to that event. See the links to pubsub in my answer for examples.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you, just click "GoTo Blue Panel" button.

```
import wx
import wx.lib
import wx.lib.flatnotebook as FNB

class MyFlatNotebook(FNB.FlatNotebook):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        mystyle = FNB.FNB_DROPDOWN_TABS_LIST|\
        FNB.FNB_FF2|\
        FNB.FNB_SMART_TABS|\
        FNB.FNB_X_ON_TAB
        super(MyFlatNotebook, self).__init__(parent, style=mystyle)
        # Attributes
        self.textctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="edit me", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.blue = wx.Panel(self)
        self.blue.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)

        # Setup
        self.AddPage(self.textctrl, "Text Editor")
        self.AddPage(self.blue, "Blue Panel")

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        # Make some buttons
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, "GoTo Blue Panel")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, button)

        hbox.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.nb = MyFlatNotebook(self)
        vbox.Add(hbox, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)

    def OnButton(self, event):
        self.nb.SetSelection(1)



if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "NoteTest")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```